# How to extract text from doc file?

Tags: python, c, doc

How to extract text from doc file using C language? I need free library, with simple function like `char* doc2txt(const char*)`

Comment: Hello! This seems to be [the second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63194374/how-to-extract-text-from-pdf-file) you posted recently to announcing a library you created. Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as spam. Take a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How do I advertise on SO?](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising).

Comment: Hello! I am very sorry. Those libs are non commercial. I don`t receive any profit. I had problems with pdf and doc formats, so I just would like to help community

Comment: This is not about self-promotion, I just failed to find appropriate solution to those problems. so I posted these to easy find and test libs

Comment: I googled for doc library for python and C, and found only commercial solutions

Comment: That being the case, you may want to add (with an [edit]) a stronger disclaimer in your question stating your intentions to help avoid misunderstandings. Additionally, your answer should probably contain more than just the link to your library. A brief demonstration of how to use your library and some indication of what limitations and assumptions apply would go a long way towards improving the quality of your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any solution, so I created my own library https://github.com/uvoteam/libdoc
It can be used for Python also